# Transimpedance amplifier with biopotentials

Tags: current, circuit-design, biopotential, transimpedance

I have a PPG sensor to be specific the sensor is called " easy pulse finger sensor " which is a ( phototransisitor), can it be connected  to a transimpedance amplifier ( current to voltage converter)?! 
Because the output of the sensor as i assumed will be a current, so i should amplify and convert it to voltage inorder to put it into bandpass filter

Comment: Sure, you can connect it to a TIA. What's your question?

Comment: My question is how do i design a proper TIA suitable for my signal

Answer (score 0):

To read out a photo diode you can indeed very well use a TIA.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transimpedance_amplifier) tells all the information you need to design a circuit. 
Find a suitable operational amplifier with a low input referred noise (just search for low noise opamp).

The formula for the output voltage is simply:

$$\frac{V_{out}}{I_P} = -R_f$$

The output voltage is buffered by the amplifier so you can directly filter it in the way you want it.

[image]